# Installing JDK8 on DIY openshift

Tags: java-8, openshift, openshift-cartridge

I'm trying to upgrade my `Openshift` `DIY` instance to `JDK8`.
I'm following [this](http://www.scriptscoop.net/t/5f1680ab898f/jdk-8-support-at-diy-cartridge-in-openshift.html) tutoial, but I'm facing a disk quota exceeded problem. I am able to download the `tar.gz` file, but cannot unzip it. What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JDK8 is actually already installed on the servers in this location (/etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.8.0) which is referenced here: (https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-jbossas/env/OPENSHIFT_JBOSSAS_JDK8)

You should just need to setup environment variables for your JAVA_HOME.

Comment: ok that worked! p.s also had to add the bin folder to the PATH. Where did you find it? I find it very difficult to follow openshift docs..

Comment: If I ssh to the remote server and append the `jdk/bin` folder to the PATH it works and I have java 8. But it doesn't stick, so if I use `git push` it is removed from the PATH. setting JAVA_HOME is not enough.. any solution?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the full path to java8 when you start your application?

Comment: Yea just did that, was just about to notify. Thanks a lot!